# Java Android display message before closing the activity (pressing back)

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get to display a message on my Android Application before the app is closed (when user presses the back message).

What I did till now is this:

```
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap  {

@JavascriptInterface
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init();

    // new code
    super.setBooleanProperty("keepRunning", true);

    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splashscreen);
    super.setStringProperty("loadingDialog", "Loading Silver Angel ...");

    appView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "MainActivity");

    super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 10000); 
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html",10000);

}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    //Handle the back button
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        //Ask the user if they want to quit
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)            
        .setTitle("Closing Silver Angel")
        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to close this application?")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                //Stop the activity
                MainActivity.this.finish();    
            }

        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", null)
        .show();

        return true;
    }
    else {
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
}
```

I also tried to use this method instead:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Closing Activity")
        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to close this activity?")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();    
        }

    })
    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
    .show();
}
```

The Problem I am facing is that when I am testing on Nexus 7 tablet, the message displays for 1 second and disappears with the application closing itself too.

Thanks

Comment: the user: 'I just pressed back, why would you ask me if I want to quit the app?'

Comment: Because this app is not for normal users but for older people who can by accident close it.

Comment: @njzk2 it makes sense sometimes to ask users for confirming the app exit. frequently users click back button repeatedly to go back to previous activities and exit accidentally. If restarting the application is time consuming (some initialization probably required) applying some confirmation method doesnt harm

Answer (score 2):

```
ya that's obvious as you have not told which button has been pressed use this code


@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                switch (which){
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                    finish();
                    break;

                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                    break;
                }
            }
        };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.do_you_really_want_to_exit)).setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.yes), dialogClickListener)
        .setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.no), dialogClickListener).show();
    }
```

Button_Positive will have functionality of yes here I closed the activity and Negative part left blank so nothing will happen

Answer (score 0):

You could try a `Toast`:

```
Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this,"Good Bye, User!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

A lot of apps that use the "Press Back Key Twice To Exit" method show the message as a `Toast`.

**Update:**
In your `onBackPressed()`, show a dialog box that presents a yes or no choice. If the user presses yes, call `super.onBackPressed()` else, just dismiss the dialog box.

Comment: By doing toast, it does not allow me to ask the question if he/she wants the app closed

Comment: Thats what I am doing but the message is being dispayed for 1 second and disappears